# jekyll GitHub user page build error

Tags: css, sass, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to host a blog on [GitHub Pages](http://github.com/pages) using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com). I was able to run the blog locally without trouble. I am using the `username.github.io/username` repository. I created new blog using the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/xxx/xxx.github.io.git
jekyll new blog
cd blog
jekyll serve
```

This works locally. I've then committed and pushed to the git repo using the commands below:

```
cd ..
git add *
git commit -m "testing"
git push
```

The page build failed with the following error:

> The file `blog/css/main.scss` contains syntax errors. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-markdown-errors.
>
> If you have any questions please contact us at https://github.com/contact.

The main.scss is as below,

```
---
# Only the main Sass file needs front matter (the dashes are enough)
---
@charset "utf-8";



// Our variables
$base-font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
$base-font-size:   16px;
$small-font-size:  $base-font-size * 0.875;
$base-line-height: 1.5;

$spacing-unit:     30px;

$text-color:       #111;
$background-color: #fdfdfd;
$brand-color:      #2a7ae2;

$grey-color:       #828282;
$grey-color-light: lighten($grey-color, 40%);
$grey-color-dark:  darken($grey-color, 25%);

// Width of the content area
$content-width:    800px;

$on-palm:          600px;
$on-laptop:        800px;



// Using media queries with like this:
// @include media-query($on-palm) {
//     .wrapper {
//         padding-right: $spacing-unit / 2;
//         padding-left: $spacing-unit / 2;
//     }
// }
@mixin media-query($device) {
    @media screen and (max-width: $device) {
        @content;
    }
}



// Import partials from `sass_dir` (defaults to `_sass`)
@import
        "base",
        "layout",
        "syntax-highlighting"
;
```

I think the problem is that the css are not generated from the scss. I am not sure though. Whats the problem here?

Comment: I don't know anything about Jekyll, but those dashes and hash style comments at the top of the file are not valid Sass.

Comment: @cimmanon I removed the dashes. I did not get an error but I could not see any styling in the blog. Just a simple text page.

Comment: in the _site/css folder its still main.scss. Should that be compiled to CSS? [Anyone who is familiar to jekyll can tell me about this]

Comment: Can you provide a code repository url ? It's quickest to get a rapid view and find a solution. –

Comment: Which version of jekyll are you using and are you using the `github-pages` gem locally?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a `_sass` directory. Check out my project which has a `main.scss` (located in css/main.scss) file which imports partials from the _sass directory --> https://github.com/wiredsister/wiredsister.github.io